# How to get notified when the process invoked using Apache Commons Exec has stopped?

Tags: apache, exec

I am invoking a java process using Apache exec library. I need to do some operation if the process is forcefully stopped ( using task manager or some other way). Is there any option available in exec library ? I found a waitfor() operation in ResultHandler, which is doing a busy wait. Is there any notification mechanism available ?

Comment: Looks like you are in need of a [Watchdog timer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchdog_timer).

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the *exit status* to reflect if the process had been forceably killed.

See [the tutorial](http://commons.apache.org/exec/tutorial.html) and in particular reference to your comment, this section:

> Your worker thread will block until the print process has finished or
>   was killed by the watchdog. Therefore executing the print job
>   asynchronously will do the trick. In this example we create an
>   instance of 'ExecuteResultHandler' and pass it to the 'Executor'
>   instance in order to execute the process asynchronously. The
>   'resultHandler' picks up any offending exception or the process exit
>   code

Comment: But still I need to do a busy wait on it right? Is there any notification kind of mechanism available?

Comment: Yeah. When I call a waitFor its internally doing a sleep for 50ms duration in while loop and checking if process has terminated.

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked a long time ago but I stumbled upon it today...

Here is the solution: you just have to setup a [ExecuteResultHandler](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/exec/ExecuteResultHandler.html) and pass it to the [execute method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/exec/DefaultExecutor.html#execute(org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine,%20org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteResultHandler)). Then no active wait involved. Like this:

```
DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onProcessComplete(int exitValue) {
        super.onProcessComplete(exitValue);
        log.info("Process finished");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProcessFailed(ExecuteException e) {
        super.onProcessFailed(e);
        log.info("Process failed miserably");
    }
};

String process = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Acrobat Reader DC\\Reader\\AcroRd32.exe";
CommandLine cmdLine = new CommandLine(process);
cmdLine.addArgument("C:\\Users\\francois.marot\\Downloads\\UtiliserLesDernieres DLL.pdf");

DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
// the watchdog purpose is to kill the process after a specified timeout
SphereExecutionWatchdog watchdog = new SphereExecutionWatchdog(5000);
executor.setWatchdog(watchdog);
executor.execute(cmdLine, resultHandler);
```